# How to install mysql shell in centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos7

i'm trying to set up mysql shell in Centos 7 by following the instructions in this document

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install-linux-quick.html

i was able to set up the repo for centos 7 but when i try to install, it seems it's installing the mysql-shell for Centos 8 and i'm getting what i believe is a gcc error even if gcc is installed because of it

[image]

i then tried installing from their direct downloads page here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/ by picking Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 / Oracle Linux 8 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Package and installing `yum localinstall` but while the installation was successful, the mysql shell still didn't come up

[image]
[image]

has anyone been able to install mysql shell in centos 7? how did you go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong command for it. Use this instead:

```
[developer@web01-compute ~]$ mysqlsh
```

Then once you're in you can type:

```
\c 127.0.0.1
```

To connect to any locally running instances of mysql. Or just use the ip address of whatever mysql instance you are trying to connect to. Be prepared to give password for it.

```
\sql
```

lets you begin typing normal sql commands.